# Is there any way to make output of my SQLPLUS script look better?

Tags: windows, oracle, cmd, sqlplus

I am new to sql.I would like to ask if there is any way to format my output to look more complex and more like one table?

My script looks like this

```
spool "\\PathToPutOutputInTextFile"
SELECT a.ARCHIVEID, count(*) as "Number of Documents", ROUND(SUM(c.CLENGTH)/1024/1024,2) as "Documents Size in MB"
        FROM ds_doc d
        INNER JOIN ds_arch a ON d.ARCHIVENO = a.ARCHIVENO
        INNER JOIN ds_comp c ON d.DOCIDNO = c.DOCIDNO
        GROUP BY a.ARCHIVEID;
spool off;
```

And I was also able to automatize this with .bat file that looks like this

```
sqlplus usr/pass@nameofdb @D:\IXTENT\monitoring\ASCheck.sql -path "\\PathToPutOutputInTextFile\test.txt
```

I was somehow manage to make this somehow work but my output looks like sh..t :/

This is my output.

```
ARCHIVEID

Number of Documents

Documents Size in MB

test_rt                                                                39
                        3.03

IL                                                                                  36
                        104

TN                                                                         139823
                20683.57


ARCHIVEID

Number of Documents

Documents Size in MB


T5                                                                               6931
               331978.15

TA                                                                                  4
                        .34

TT                                                                                 23
                        3.09
```

Is there any way to make it complex and look more like one table?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might also want to explore [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html) and the `sqlformat` options, particularly `set sqlformat ansiconsole`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
set echo off verify off head off feed off term off lines 120 pages 0
col "Number of Documents" for 9999999999
col "Documents Size in MB" for 9999999999
col ARCHIVEID for a30
spool "\\PathToPutOutputInTextFile"
SELECT a.ARCHIVEID, count(*) as "Number of Documents", ROUND(SUM(c.CLENGTH)/1024/1024,2) as "Documents Size in MB"
        FROM ds_doc d
        INNER JOIN ds_arch a ON d.ARCHIVENO = a.ARCHIVENO
        INNER JOIN ds_comp c ON d.DOCIDNO = c.DOCIDNO
        GROUP BY a.ARCHIVEID;
spool off;
```

However, if you want to use this file to load data in another database, a good option is to use `set markup csv` , guessing you have Oracle 12 or higher.

```
set echo off verify off head off feed off term off lines 120 pages 0
set markup csv delimiter ";"
spool "\\PathToPutOutputInTextFile"
SELECT a.ARCHIVEID, count(*) as "Number of Documents", ROUND(SUM(c.CLENGTH)/1024/1024,2) as "Documents Size in MB"
        FROM ds_doc d
        INNER JOIN ds_arch a ON d.ARCHIVENO = a.ARCHIVENO
        INNER JOIN ds_comp c ON d.DOCIDNO = c.DOCIDNO
        GROUP BY a.ARCHIVEID;
spool off;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way; format **columns**.

For example:

```
SQL> select * from emp where rownum < 3;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300
        30
```

By setting columns' format, you'd get

```
SQL> col empno format 99999
SQL> col ename format a8
SQL> col mgr   format 9999
SQL> col sal   format 9G990
SQL> col comm  format 990
SQL>
SQL> select * from emp where rownum < 3;

 EMPNO ENAME    JOB         MGR HIREDATE    SAL COMM     DEPTNO
------ -------- --------- ----- -------- ------ ---- ----------
  7369 SMITH    CLERK      7902 17.12.80    800              20
  7499 ALLEN    SALESMAN   7698 20.02.81  1.600  300         30

SQL>
```

If line is *too short*, make it *longer*:

```
SQL> set linesize 120
```

Or, make the page larger:

```
SQL> set pagesize 1000
```

There are different options you can use; see SQL*Plus documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format your query output, they you can use RPAD(field_name, number of spaces) ... for ex RPAD(Name, 50) ... it will fix the width of each field while printing and will look in sync.